# distance calculations between sites in a python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I'm working with long and latitude coordinates in Python and i'm trying to find the distance between two sites in a data frame, however, I am struggling to find out how to do this in pandas. if long = x and lat = y, I understand the logic to calculate the distance sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2), but I do not understand how I would go about this in a data frame. My task is further complicated by the fact that I am trying to find the top 3 sites that are nearest to the site in row 1 (eventually I have to iterate through all the rows).

Question is, is there a better way to attack this problem than iterating through row by row? As I also have to find nearest k sites to each row, i'm not sure if iterrow() would be the best solution, but I can't think of a cleverer matrix way to go about solving this problem. See sample data below. So I need a column "Nearest sites", and for row 1, nearest sites would be: 6 followed by 4, then 5, so I need row 1 to display like this:

[image]

Thanks.

sample data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy makes this straightforward and easy to do even with huge datasets. See below.

```
# Turn Pandas dataframe into ndarray
data = data.to_numpy(dtype='float')

# Make a reference array out of first row
ref = np.tile(data[0], (data.shape[0], 1))

# Use vectorized computation to find distance for each site
dist = (data[:,1:3] - ref[:,1:3]) ** 2     # Replace 1:3 with appropriate column indices for lat and long
dist = np.sum(dist, axis=1)
dist = np.sqrt(dist).resize((data.shape[0], 1))

# Concatenate distance on to data
data = np.concatenate((data, dist), axis=1)

# Sort resulting ndarray by distance
data = data[np.argsort(data[:,-1])]

# Get IDs of 3 closest sitaes
ids = [data[i, 0] for i in range(1, 4)]
```

This code with quickly return you the ID values of the three closest sites to the first row of your data. If you want to find the 3 closest sites to other rows too just change `np.tile(data[0], (data.shape[0], 1))` to `np.tile(data[i], (data.shape[0], 1))` for the ith row. If you are going to do it for multiple rows, it also would be smart to create a copy of your data each time and use that so your original data remains unchanged.

Once you have the IDs of the closest sites, you can do whatever you want with them. Put them in another table to make them look pretty or do what you want with them. If you need to turn an ndarray back into a Pandas dataframe just use `pandas.DataFrame(ndarray)`.

Comment: Thanks! Much more efficient than what I was planning to do! Now to try to understand it!